# Выход за предел массива c#

Tags: c#, массивы

Дан массив. Сравнить первый и второй элементы массива. Если второй элемент меньше первого, то поменять их местами. Затем то же самое сделать со вторым и третьим, …, предпоследним и последним элементами. Какое число окажется в результате в последнем элементе массива?

```
 public static void swap(int a, int b)
        {
            int tmp;
            tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[10];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = rand.Next(20);
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }
            for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
            {
                if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
                {
                        swap(array[i], array[i + 1]); 
                }   
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }
        }
```

На моменте if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) у меня происходит ошибка. И индекс выходит за пределы массива. Подскажите как это решить?

Comment: Надо написать код так, чтобы индекс не выходил за пределы.

Comment: Это понятно, но как в этом случае решить задачу?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сравнить 10 и 11 элемент массива. Но у вас их всего 10. И метод swap нерабочий, найдите рабочий, примеров полно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо либо проверять граничные случаи и не допускать варианта сравнения с `array[i + 1]` (т.е. делать if до проверки с `array[i + 1]`), либо циклы ограничивать до длины - 1, т.к. сравнение последнего элемента массива с элементом `array[i + 1]` не имеет смысла